Fixing the Information tool for mobile devices on a QGIS2WEB generated map
I've used QGIS2WEB to make a web map. It's hosted on GITHUB for now. The map is here: https://kujawa0445.github.io/OCT24_TESTING/#15/44.4993/-73.1799
The map works well for me w some image pop-ups and a way to get a full screen rendering of the images.
On desktop/laptop, the information button works but it doesn't on mobile devices.  Not sure if there's a fix that I could implement in the rendering process or in the resulting Leaflet/CSS files.
I put some HTML code in the information and as I said it works (including a link and a graphic) but not on mobile devices.

Not really a GIS question, completely HTML/JS related one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908339/js-touch-equivalent-for-mouseenter

In my smartphone the "i" is visible and I can click it. The message opens and if I click out it closes. The only problem I see is that the element is too high and I can't read the first words of the message. Is this the problem?

TomazicM. New to this so apologies for a non-GIS question.  Your link didn't really help me as I am too new to this to understand the css coding discussion in the link.  Thanks anyway.

Sets a larger width for the abstract element in small monitors.
Add this css in your index.html file before closing the </head> section.
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .abstract {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}
</style>


Thanks for the code suggestion "@media only" etc.  I am not sure where to place that in the code for the map.  I can track the abstract set up (which does the i button content) but not sure where to place the segment you suggest.  I am pretty much an amateur w the code.  I am going to paste in the content of the index.html file.  The abstract code is low down.  If you can suggest where to place the segment you gave it'd be very helpful.  Shoot, I can't paste all of the code from index.html.  I can't put the abstract segment alone.  Thanks anyway.

One other thing -- my portable devices are Iphone and Ipad and the i isn't active in either.

I updated my answer including "style". Take all the code including opening and closing the style and insert it before closing the  in index.html file.

Sorry but I can't test on Apple devices. However the button is made in HTML, it seems strange to me that an Apple browser cannot reproduce it

Thanks for the direction on the edited code segment.  I will try it.  On the Iphone/Ipad the "i" appears but won't open.  I tried deleting the image and shortening text.  Still no joy.  If I just put text and a link in (inside of QGIS) it shows up but the "i" interactivity is gone (on laptop and I devices) but the text appears.  I will try your code segment and report back.  Many thanks.
